# Cobertura integration test support was released with... debug mode enabled?

Tags: maven, unit-testing, integration-testing, cobertura, maven-cobertura-plugin

I'm trying to put to work the coverage numbers for my integration tests. I'm using the plugin cobertura. I'm using the 2.7 version (last version) they released the support for integration tests.

I put to work, the final report is correct. But when I started the build and it's time the integration tests to run, a LOT of lines appear in my console, in the same way if I was started the maven build in debug mode (I'm not!). Example:

```
[DEBUG] Adding QuerySpace : uid = <gen:0> -> org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.EntityQuerySpaceImpl@357ea46e]
[DEBUG] Visiting attribute path : persons
[DEBUG] Adding QuerySpace : uid = <gen:1> -> org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.CollectionQuerySpaceImpl@11e97dff]
[DEBUG] Adding QuerySpace : uid = <gen:2> -> org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.EntityQuerySpaceImpl@3a5537e6]
[DEBUG] Visiting attribute path : id
[DEBUG] Visiting attribute path : name
```

Mostly than from Hibernate Framework. If I change back to report only unit tests, everything is back to normal on log.

So... this plugin is really stable and reliable? The last and only version with integration test support was the 2.7 and I'm not sure if this behavior is my fault.

Comment: I found someone if a related issue on Github: https://github.com/mojohaus/cobertura-maven-plugin/issues/14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [issue](https://github.com/mojohaus/cobertura-maven-plugin/issues/14) about this problem on the project repository. Sadly, the Cobertura project seems a little abandoned. So, I will try to use JaCoCo instead of Cobertura.